# Is it possible to use default Windows 7 themes in Windows Embedded Standard 7?

Tags: windows-7, embedded, aero

Is it possible to use Windows 7 default themes (such as Windows 7 Basic) on Windows Embedded Standard 7 ? If so, how ?

I believe themes include common controls styling i.e. they give an "Aero" look to your progress bar instead of the classic Windows 95-ish one.

The context of my question is a migration of a WPF application from a Windows 7 workstation to a Windows Embedded Standard 7 embedded device.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, here is the solution:

Uri uri = new Uri("PresentationFramework.Aero;V3.0.0.0;31bf3856ad364e35;component\themes/aero.normalcolor.xaml", UriKind.Relative);

Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(Application.LoadComponent(uri) as ResourceDictionary);

There is a blog article about the topic

http://arbel.net/blog/archive/2006/11/03/Forcing-WPF-to-use-a-specific-Windows-theme.aspx